# Error: No match for call to 'boost::.......'

Tags: c++, publish-subscribe, ros, boost-bind

I am trying to modify another code. Just wanted to add another subscriber to it. This is the skeleton of the code:

```
namespace my_server
{
    a_server::a_server(ros::NodeHandle n)
    : nh()
    {
        ros::NodeHandle n(n_);
        sub1 = new message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> (nh(), "/x", 5);
        sub2 = new tf::MessageFilter<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> (*sub1, sub3, xyz, 5);
        sub2->registerCallback(boost::bind(&a_server::callback, this, _1));
    }
    a_server::~a_server()
    {
    .....
    }

    void a_server::callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr& cl)
    {
    ....
    }
}
```

And here is the header file:

```
namespace my_server
{
    class a_server
    {
        public:
        a_server(ros::NodeHandle n_ = ros::NodeHandle("~"));
        virtual ~a_server();

        virtual void callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr& cl);
        protected:
            ros::NodeHandle n;
            message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>* sub1;
            tf::MessageFilter<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>* sub2;
            tf::TransformListener sub3;
    }
}
```

Now I want to add another subscriber to it. Do not need to bind it with previous subscriber. I am doing it by adding this line after previous subscribers.

```
ros::Subscriber  sub4 = m_nh.subscribe<geometry_msgs::Point>("/y", 1, &a_server::callback2);
```

And added a callback function after `void a_server::callback`:

```
void a_server::callback2(geometry_msgs::Point &a)
{
    ....
}
```

And this to header file under `protected`:

```
void callback2(geometry_msgs::Point &a);
```

This is the error that i am getting :

```
Error: 
no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf1<void, my_server::a_server, geometry_msgs::Point_<std::allocator<void> >&>) (const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Point_<std::allocator<void> > >&)’
BOOST_FUNCTION_RETURN(boost::mem_fn(*f)(BOOST_FUNCTION_ARGS));
```

I understand this has something to do with `boost::bind` usage in previous subscribers. But I don't want to change them. Just need to add another subscriber whose callback function will update a global variable that will in return be used by previous callback function.

Answer (score 0):

So after loosing precious 6 hours. This is how it is solved. Subscriber was added like this:

```
ros::Subscriber sub4 = nh.subscribe<geometry_msgs::Point>("/y", 1, boost::bind(&a_server::callback2, this, _1));
```

Callback function was written like this:

```
void a_server::callback2(const geometry_msgs::Point::ConstPtr& a)
{
    ....
}
```

Header file was added with this under `Public:`

```
void callback2(const geometry_msgs::Point::ConstPtr& a);
```